# Use File TypesMan to change extension setting, but it show "this file type may affect the following extensions"

Tags: windows-7, file-extension, file-type

I want to change extensions default icon, so use File TypesMan. When I change some file setting, the panel show notice:

> Notice - Changing the properties of this file type may affect the
> following extensions: .css, .gitignore, .js, .TS

[image]

So I can't change the setting that will change other extention.
Could I cancel this "effect"?

System: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

The FileTypesMan version history lists this addition:

> When editing a file type that shares multiple file extensions, FileTypesMan will display a list of file extensions that might be affected by editing the file type.

This means I can explain how this feature is supposed to work. In Windows, file type information is stored in the registry. The file extension is used to look up the file types ProgId (Programmatic Identifier) and inside the ProgId key the icon location is stored. Or at least this is what the official Microsoft documentation tells you. The UserChoice value was added much later and is undocumented.

We can first look at a scenario where this feature works correctly.

The .htm and .html file extensions often point to the same ProgId because they are really both the same file type. If you tried to edit the .html icon FileTypesMan would probably warn you that your changes will affect .htm as well (and you want that in this case).

In your case however, it warns you about unrelated file types. GitIgnore files and CSS files have nothing in common so we are looking at a bug in FileTypesMan or something weird in the type registrations on your system.

We can see from your screenshot that the .css extension is mapped to the `CSSFile` ProgId and that seems perfectly normal. If you try to edit the .js extension that is also listed as affected and it also lists `CSSFile` as its ProgId then while technically valid and legal, it would be extremely uncommon and I would claim there is something wrong with the type registrations on your system.

If that is not the case then I would guess that the UserChoice is the source of the notice message. I can tell by the UserChoice value that at some point the "Open with" feature was used to open a .css file in the Sublime editor. It makes sense that this has also been done with other unrelated file types and FileTypeMan (and Windows?) now thinks they are connected.

What I cannot answer with 100% certainty is if FileTypesMan will change the icon for all the types it warns about or just for .css files. Since the current icon location it lists is for DreamWeaver and not Sublime, my guess is that it will only edit the CSSFile ProgId and leave all the other types alone. If the current icon you see for .css files is a DreamWeaver icon then it is probably going to work. If you see the Sublime icon for .css files then changing the icon might do nothing or actually change the icon for all the file types it warns about.